# How to debug "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use"

Tags: php, web

I have been trying to update an entity, but I have to update them all at update page, else it throws error:

Here's my code:

```
// to verify if user is an admin
    <?php include "include/uni_header.php"?>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['update'])){
        if ($_GET['update'] == null){
            header("Location: error/error.php");
        }else{
            $hlp = $_GET['update'];
        }
    }else{
        header("Location: error/error.php");
    }
    ?>
        <!-- mail -->
    
        <div class="latest-albums">
            <div class="container">
                <h3 class="agileits_w3layouts_head"> <span>Update existing</span></h3>
                <div class="wthree_latest_albums_grids gallery">
                    <div class="col-md-9 agile_mail_grid_left">
                       // here i am trying to fetch all value & putting them on the field
                        <?php
                                $sql = "select * from music where id=$hlp";
                                $getter = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getter)) {
                                    $id = $row['id'];
                                    $title = $row['title'];
                                    $singer = $row['singer'];
                                    $description = $row['description'];
                                    $length = $row['length'];
                                    $relese_date = $row['relese_date'];
                                    $lyrics = $row['lyrics'];
                                    $genere = $row['genere'];
                                    $songs = $row['songs'];
                                    $thumbnail = $row['thumbnail'];
                                    $language = $row['language'];
                                    $album_tag = $row['album_tag'];
                                    $youtube_id = $row['youtube_id'];
                                    $feature_tag = $row['feature_tag'];
                                }
                        ?>
                        // trying to update
                        <?php
                        if (isset($_POST['submits'])){
                            $title = $_POST['name'];
                            $singer = $_POST['singer'];
                            $description = $_POST['description'];
                            $length = $_POST['length'];
                            $date = $_POST['release_date'];
                            $lyrics = $_POST['lyrics'];
                            $category = $_POST['cat'];
                            $language = $_POST['cat1'];
                            $youtube = substr($_POST['youtube'], 17);
                            $album = $_POST['album'];
    
                            //thumbnail
                            $p_image = $_FILES['images']['name'];
                            $post_image_temp = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
                            move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "thumbnail/$p_image");
    
                            //songs
                            $upload_file = $_FILES['files']['name'];
                            $temps = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
                            move_uploaded_file($temps, "songs/$upload_file");
                            //query
                                $query = "update music set title='{$title}', singer='{$singer}', description='{$description}', length='{$length}', relese_date='{$date}', lyrics='{$lyrics}', genere={$category}, songs='{$upload_file}', thumbnail='{$upload_file}', language={$language}, album_tag='{$album}', youtube_id='{$youtube}' where id={$hlp}";
                                $sender = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                                echo "error".mysqli_error($connection);
    
    
    
                        }
                        ?>
                       // pushing previously pulled value as user can see old values, it helps to update.
                        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <label for="name">Enter Song Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"><br>
    
                            <label for="email">Singer</label>
                            <input type="text" name="singer" placeholder="Singer" value="<?php echo $singer; ?>"><br>
    
                            <label for="description">Description</label>
                            <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>"><br>
    
                            <label for="length">Run Time</label>
                            <input type="text" name="length" placeholder="Run Time" value="<?php echo $length; ?>"><br>
    
                            <label for="images">Upload the song</label>
                            <input type="file" name="files" class="btn btn-default">
    
                            <label for="album">Album name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="album" placeholder="Album name" value="<?php echo $album_tag; ?>"><br>
    
                            <label for="youtube">Paste the Short URL only</label>
                            <input type="text" name="youtube" placeholder="ex: https://youtu.be/xxxxx" value="<?php echo $youtube_id; ?>"><br>
                            *This field only accepts SHORT URL <b>(open the song vid->share->copy link)</b>
                            <br><br>
    
                            <label for="country1">Choose Language</label>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <select id="country1" class="dropdown" name="cat1">
                                    <?php
                                            $sql1 = "select * from language where id=$language";
                                            $getter1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);
                                            while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getter1)){
                                                $language=$r['language'];
                                            }
                                    ?>
                                    <option class="dropdown-header" value=""><?php echo $language; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                    $querys = "select * from language";
                                    $sends = mysqli_query($connection, $querys);
    
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sends)) {
                                        $id = $row['id'];
                                        $language = $row['language'];
    
                                        echo "<option class='dropdown-item' value='{$id}'>{$language}</option>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
    
                            </div>
                            <br><br>
    
                            <label for="release_date">Release Date</label>
                            <input type="date" autocomplete="off" name="release_date" id="date" placeholder="Relese Date" value="<?php echo $relese_date; ?>"><br>
    
                            <br>
                            <label>Upload A Thumbnail Picture</label>
                            <input type="file" name="images" class="btn btn-default">
                            <br>
    
                            <label>Post the lyrics</label>
                            <textarea name="lyrics" placeholder="Description of the book"  id = "body"></textarea>
                            <br>
    
                            <label for="Genre">Choose Genre</label>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <select id="country" class="dropdown" name="cat">
                                    <option class="dropdown-header" value=""><?php echo $genere; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                    $querys = "select * from category";
                                    $sends = mysqli_query($connection, $querys);
    
                                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sends)) {
                                        $id = $row['id'];
                                        $category = $row['title'];
    
                                        echo "<option class='dropdown-item' value='{$id}'>{$category}</option>";
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
    
                            </div>
    
                            <br><br>
    
                            <input type="submit" value="Post Your Song Now" name="submits">
                        </form>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- //mail -->
    <?php include "include/about_footer.php"?>
```

As I am clicking **Submit** it's throwing me an error like below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near ' album_tag='fefef222', youtube_id='' where id=19' at line 1

My database structure is:

> CREATE TABLE music ( id int(3) NOT NULL, title varchar(255) NOT NULL, singer varchar(255) NOT NULL, description text NOT NULL, length varchar(255) NOT NULL, relese_date varchar(255) NOT NULL, likes int(3) NOT NULL, lyrics text NOT NULL, genere int(3) NOT NULL, songs text NOT NULL, thumbnail text NOT NULL, language int(3) NOT NULL, album_tag varchar(255) NOT NULL, youtube_id varchar(255) NOT NULL, feature_tag varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'general' ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
>
> CREATE TABLE language ( id int(11) NOT NULL, language varchar(255) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Where is my fault?

Comment: actually 'language' is an integer field... Should i use quotes for that too?

Comment: no don't use quotes for that

Comment: can i see your database structure?

Comment: ok hold on. will reply with a code fix if necessary

Comment: Is there a value for the field 'cat1' - the options seem to have `value=""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label for="country1">Choose Language</label>
<div class="btn-group">
    <select id="country1" class="dropdown" name="cat1">
        <?php
                $sql1 = "select * from language where id=$language";
                $languageId = $language;

                $getter1 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql1);
                while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getter1)){
                    $language=$r['language'];
                }
        ?>
        <!-- you have an empty value which would result to 
            language =, album_tag='fefef222', 
             -->
        <!-- which is wrong.. -->


        <!-- you need the id, just incase the user doesn't alter the select box for another language -->
        <!-- this is the default language -->
        <option class="dropdown-header" value="<?=$languageId?>"><?php echo $language; ?></option>
        <?php
        $querys = "select * from language";
        $sends = mysqli_query($connection, $querys);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sends)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $language = $row['language'];

            echo "<option class='dropdown-item' value='{$id}'>{$language}</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select>

</div>
<br><br>


<!-- now your  query would run fine -->
<?php

$query = "update music set title='{$title}', singer='{$singer}', description='{$description}', length='{$length}', relese_date='{$date}', lyrics='{$lyrics}', genere={$category}, songs='{$upload_file}', thumbnail='{$upload_file}', language={$language}, album_tag='{$album}', youtube_id='{$youtube}' where id={$hlp}";

?>
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we encourage answerers to add some explanation, rather than just answering using code on its own. We feel that some explanatory text makes an answer more useful for future readers.